# Cannot control display resolution with 16.04 LTS

Tags: display, display-resolution

I am using HP Pavilion Desktop. Came with Windows 8. I have been using dual boot with ubuntu for about a year without major problems.

Recently updated to 16.04 LTS (from 15.10) and at first could not boot. Got in using recovery mode and tried some fixes (Secure Boot is disabled). Several posts recommend solutions related to NVidia drivers. I tried this one:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-364
```

and was able to boot, but got into a login loop (kept asking for the password even though it was correct). Finally got out of the login loop using:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

but now my display resolution is stuck at 800x600 and I cannot change it (very inconvenient to work). I think this has to do with drivers for Radeon card. This is what I get for my graphics card (probably did not need to try any fixes related to NVidia):

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7560D]
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I need to learn to insert screen input/output. Any ideas about how to get a normal resolution with this new Radeon driver? Most of the postings I encounter deal with performance issues (speed). I wish that were my problem. I need to scroll the width and height of the screen more than three times over in order to see what should normally fit in one screen.